# AWS ami STACK server FTP permission denied Error:File transfer failed

Tags: server-setup, aws

I have create one server AWS ami STACK then i have connect FTP with user and file but i have not upload any file in server 
Error:  /var/www/magento/dev/index123.php: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed

Answer (score 0):

You can try edit this file if this parameter is commented or not present : 
**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
local_enable=YES
 write_enable=YES
 chroot_local_user=YES
 /home/username/files
 chown root:root /home/username
```

**then run command :**

```
service vsftpd restart
```

This solution might help  you.

Comment: File is not located in this path :-  /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: You need to use function such as 'locate  vsftpd' and 'find vsfpd' etc to find file . this location is for apache servers.

Comment: /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/vsftpd.aug
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/tests/test_vsftpd.aug,
/usr/share/sosreport/sos/plugins/vsftpd.py,
/usr/share/sosreport/sos/plugins/__pycache__/vsftpd.cpython-35.pyc